# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'NoneType'(Stateful LSTM Keras)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, sequence

So I have a trained LSTM model with which I am trying to predict future values. The model is stateful as seen below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units=50,batch_size=1, input_shape=(None, 1),stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(GRU(units=50,stateful=True,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(.1))
model.add(GRU(1, return_sequences=True,stateful=True))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x * 1.0012))
model.load_weights("weights.h5")
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

When I try to predict on the entire data and then pass that through in a loop to predict future vals I get the title error. This ONLY occurs if steps is set.

If I set steps with a batch_size it tells me to set batch_size to None and if I do that I get the error above. Very strange. What's going on here? It also will work if I do not set steps and set batch to any int divisible by the # of samples.

Below is the prediction code:

```
model.reset_states()
predictions = model.predict(entire_data,batch_size=1)
futureElement = predictions[:,-1:,:]
futureElements = []
forecast1 = []
futureElements.append(futureElement)
for i in range(time):
    futureElement = model.predict(futureElement,batch_size=None,steps=60)
    forecast1.append(futureElement)
```

Comment: Have you checked if your `entire_data` contains any entry that is `None`? As far as I can tell your model is expecting an `int` data type and is receiving a `None` data type.

Comment: It does not. My model actually expects float64 I believe which makes the error all the more confusing. I have read of quite a few issues using steps in this way with a stateful LSTM.

For reference, my data is just the [bitstamp_csv](https://www.kaggle.com/mczielinski/bitcoin-historical-data/data) on kaggle.